# For which values of $r$ the sequence $nr^n$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

We have the sequence

$$nr^n$$

and we want to find the values of $r$ such that $nr^n$ converges. What I did:

for $|r|<1$ we have $r = \frac{1}{k}$ where $k>1$ or $k<-1$ so:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} nr^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}  n\frac{1}{k^n}$$

but $k^n > n^2$ for large values of $n$ (because $|k|>1$), so:

$$k^n > n^2 \implies \frac{1}{k^n}<\frac{1}{n^2}\implies 0<\frac{n}{k^n}<\frac{1}{n} = 0$$

so the sequence converges. Am I rigth? Therefore I'm only left to show that the sequence diverges for $|r|$>1?

Comment: That's right, and it will diverge for $|r| > 1$. What happens when $|r| = 1$? You'll have two different cases to consider, they won't behave the same.